# An error occurred while reading the restart journal

Tags: powershell, azure

When attempting to run the Azure Storage SDK tool `AzCopy.exe (v5.1.1)` from Powershell using the command syntax:

```
.\AzCopy /source:https://mystorageacct1.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/ /dest:https://mystorageacct2.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/ /sourcekey:[sourcekey] /destkey:[destkey] /S
```

I received the error:

> .\AzCopy.exe : [2017/10/04 12:59:12][ERROR] An error occurred while reading the restart journal from "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Azure\AzCopy". Detailed error: Error parsing the journal file: Journal file was generated by a different version 
>   of AzCopy.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + .\AzCopy.exe /source:"https://mystorageacct1.blob.core.windows.net/source" ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([2017/10/04 12:...sion of AzCopy.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved when deleting the contents (specifically the journal file) from:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Azure\AzCopy
```

Then executing the Powershell script again.

Comment: Glad that helped Frederik : ) Thank you. Scott.